How to export to Excel Django object where every ForeignKey object a new column with import-export lib?
I have a model represents some item on stock:
(Code has been simplified)
class StockItem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    category = models.Charfield()
    stock = models.ForeignKey(Stock) # <- Here is few stocks
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

So every StockItem may exist on different stocks but with different q-ty remained.
Is there a way to create ModelResource to export quantity remained for every stock?
Table example:
+----+--------+----------+---------+---------+
| ID |  Name  | Category | Stock A | Stock B |
+----+--------+----------+---------+---------+
|  1 | Item 1 | Cat 1    |       1 |       1 |
|  2 | Item 2 | Cat 2    |      10 |       8 |
|  3 | Item 3 | Cat 3    |      14 |      32 |
+----+--------+----------+---------+---------+

My ModelResource:
class StockItemsRemainingsResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = models.StockItem
        fields = ('name', 'category')

    def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            for item in self.get_queryset():
                stock_name = item.stock.name
                self.fields[f"quantity_{stock_name}"] = fields.Field(
                    attribute="quantity",
                    column_name=stock_name,
                    widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(
                        models.Stock,
                        "pk"
                    )
                )

I was trying to override the __init__ method but probably did it wrong.

After hours of search I was able to achive such a structure overriding export_field() after exploring some library's code.
In my case I had to create a required fields overriding __init__ method first but using a normal fields.Field class to prepare these fields for manual population in export_field() method:
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        stocks = models.Stock.objects.all()
        for stock in stocks:
            field_name = f'stock_{stock.id}'
            self.fields[field_name] = fields.Field(
                column_name=f'{stock.name}',
                attribute=field_name
            )

The final step I made is to override export_field(self, field, instance) which takes every instance on queryset iteration to every field of resource for processing. In my case I checked a field name and in case it matches with one of the stock fields I will count a q-ty of instance related to particular stock and return it (return super() otherwise).
My code :
def export_field(self, field, instance):
        # overrided to populate dynamic fields (stock quantity)
        # If field is stock ("stock_{id}") then extract and ID for querying
        # an actual quantity
        if field.attribute.startswith("stock"):
            stock_id = field.attribute.split("_")[-1]
            stock = models.Stock.objects.filter(pk=stock_id).first()
            return instance.get_stock_quantity(stock) if stock else None
        else:
            return super().export_field(field, instance)

Probably not the best approach and I have a guess it's may be achived utilizing dehydrate_method which may be assigned to field.Field(dehydrate_method=some_method()) instance but wasn't search for a solution in that direction.

The after_export() method can be overridden to modify the dataset after the initial export.
You could maybe append a column to the dataset as required.
For example, you can add something like this method to StockItemsRemainingsResource:
    def after_export(self, queryset, dataset, **kwargs):
        counts = []
        for d in dataset.dict:
            stock_count = Stock.objects.filter(d["name"]).count()
            counts.append(stock_count)
        dataset.append_col(counts, header="count")

You could play around with this to find the best way of doing this.
This will be inefficient so probably won't work well with large datasets.
See tablib docs.
